# how to remove buttons in the search buttons of tablesearch sample

Tags: iphone

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/index.html

I am a just 2 days old in iphone programming.

I downloaded the sample project from this url. When i touch the search and type my keyword i see 4 buttons say all,portable,device and desktop. Please tell me how to remove all those 4 buttons. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are scope modifier buttons. Depending how they were added in the first place, you may be able to remove them by selecting the search bar in Interface Builder, and deleting each scope entry that appears in the Scope field.

If they're added in code, you'll have to find the lines that add them and remove them. Without seeing any code, no-one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Those buttons are called Scope Buttons and are declared in the MainView.xib of your example. Just select the search bar and in the inspector on the attributes tab you will find them listed.